# Create numbered list of dynamic item in word using OpenXML

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have a requirement where my C# code will generate a list of items from database which are actually order instructions i.e. how to place an order. That numbered list will contain some hyperlinks and some discount codes in bold.

I am not sure how to take that list and convert it into word's numbered list with proper formatting. Any help please. Example of list is as below:

> 1. Navigate to http://www.google.com/ordername/basket.aspx?quantity=1&productId=23334
> 2. Enter the renewal code: **DG%$2&*JH** and press the ‘Update’ button.
> 3. Follow the check-out process and pay using a method of your choice.

All of this is generated during run time and values come from DB

I tried using `Open XML Productivity Tool` to get the code but it is too complicated where each list item above it divided into multiple parts and then appended.

Also I need this list in mid of document - using a .dotx here.

The code I tried, which partially works without any hyperlinks and bold text is below:

```
private static void AddBulletList(List<Run> runList, MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart)
    {
        Body body = mainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
        Paragraph parentPara = body.Descendants<Paragraph>().FirstOrDefault(k => k.InnerText.Contains("text after which I need numbered list"));
        Paragraph emptyPara = new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("")));
        parentPara.InsertAfterSelf(emptyPara);
        NumberingDefinitionsPart numberingPart = mainDocumentPart.NumberingDefinitionsPart;
        var numberId = numberingPart.Numbering.Elements<NumberingInstance>().Count() + 1;
        foreach (Run runItem in runList)
        {
            // Create items for paragraph properties
            var numberingProperties = new NumberingProperties(new NumberingLevelReference() { Val = 0 }, new NumberingId() { Val = numberId });
            var spacingBetweenLines1 = new SpacingBetweenLines() { After = "60" };  // Get rid of space between bullets
            var indentation = new Indentation() { Left = "720", Hanging = "360" };  // correct indentation 

            ParagraphMarkRunProperties paragraphMarkRunProperties1 = new ParagraphMarkRunProperties();
            RunFonts runFonts1 = new RunFonts() { Ascii = "Arial", HighAnsi = "Arial", EastAsia = "Calibri", ComplexScript = "Arial" };
            FontSize fontSize1 = new FontSize() { Val = "20" };
            FontSizeComplexScript fontSizeComplexScript1 = new FontSizeComplexScript() { Val = "20" };
            paragraphMarkRunProperties1.Append(runFonts1);
            paragraphMarkRunProperties1.Append(fontSize1);
            paragraphMarkRunProperties1.Append(fontSizeComplexScript1);

            // create paragraph properties
            var paragraphProperties = new ParagraphProperties(numberingProperties, spacingBetweenLines1, indentation, paragraphMarkRunProperties1);

            // Create paragraph 
            var newPara = new Paragraph(paragraphProperties);

            // Add run to the paragraph
            newPara.AppendChild(runItem);

            // Add one bullet item to the body
            //body.AppendChild(newPara);
            emptyPara.InsertAfterSelf(newPara);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "I tried using Open XML Productivity Tool to get the code but it is too complicated where each list item above it divided into multiple parts and then appended." Nonetheless that's the only way it can be done using Open XML. Code has to build the XML document as an XML document - there are no "shortcuts".

Comment: The only alternative that occurs to me is to define the content as HTML then use `AltrenativeFormatImportPart` (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.altchunk.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericwhite/2008/10/26/how-to-use-altchunk-for-document-assembly/)